# " beautiful sunrises" is an idiom in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> Looking for a partner to share everything with. My ideal mate would have similar family-oriented values. I think communication, trust and respect are the most important aspects of any relationship. I love long romantic walks, delicious  dinners, **beautiful sunrises**. I love to go out and have fun but I am also a homebody. I think first kisses are extra special because they indicate right off the bat if there is chemistry.

My first concern has to do with **beautiful sunrises** . By saying **beautiful sunrises** does she just literally mean sunrise? Or is it an idim or a slang word? May be she has an ulterior purpose to say this. Does she want to say that she want to sleep at night in her mate house and in the morning so she could see the sunrise?weird? :) I mean by saying *beautiful sunrises** is it implicit that she wants to have sex at night and sleep during the night at her date house?

Comment: I think she literally means "beautiful sunrises". Then again, I agree that it could be suggestive, too.

Comment: I would interpret it literally: she enjoys the natural beauty of the dawn. If she wrote something like "beautiful sunrises together" then it would be more suggestive, but even then it might refer to dancing or talking all night— certainly an intimate night but not necessarily sex.